# An automatic call of "node-gyp rebuild" on "npm install" and "yarn install"

Tags: npm, npm-install, yarnpkg, node-gyp, npm-scripts

I am creating a package with some native code, which will be installed globally, and now I see the following behavior:

1. `node-gyp rebuild` runs automatically on local `npm install` and when the package is installed itself.
2. When I add a custom `preinstall` script to the `package.json`, it isn't invoked anymore on `npm install` nor when the package is installed globally, so it's not compiled at all.
3. However, in case of `yarn install` `node-gyp rebuild` still runs even with a `preinstall` hook.
4. Moreover, if I add `"preinstall": "node-gyp rebuild"`, `yarn` runs my script and then invokes `node-gyp rebuild` again, so it is compiled twice.

I wonder is there any documentation describing this behavior? Cause I found nothing. I even didn't find an explicit mention that `node-gyp rebuild` runs automatically on `npm install`.
And how can I use the `preinstall` hook so that my module is compiled only once both for `npm` and `yarn`?

`npm` 6.14.6
`yarn` 1.22.4